# Get Request Callout behaving as Post - How to set requestBody on GET Request

Tags: api, integration, rest-service

I have to make an external API Callout(Salesforce to other system) of Type - GET. Also, my request will contain requestBody. So far, it seems like it is assuming it to be a POST Request as soon as I put in the requestBody. As a result, my service returns me the error :

Status Code : 405
{"Message":"The requested resource does not support http method 'POST'."}

However, I cannot get the service converted to a POST. How can I make sure that I am able to send the requestBody for a GET Request in Salesforce?

Comment: Are you making an apex callout to an external custom implemented web service? Or making a call to a web service implemented in Salesforce using apex? May be provide some code snippet?

Comment: I am making a callout to external web service using Apex

Comment: Ok. Based on your question text, I guess this external web service is a custom implementation that you (or the team you interact with) might have access to. Have you checked if this external system is treating the request as POST (because of the present of request body)? If that's the case then there is nothing that could be done from apex side.

Comment: I have checked with POSTMAN, and it is working fine on POSTMAN with Get Request Type, however, I keep receiving the error from apex.

Comment: Looks like this is the default behavior of Http & HttpRequest objects and there is no definitive article from SF on how to force the HTTP method. Can you try this `request.setHeader('X-HTTP-Method-Override', 'GET')` or `request.setHeader('Access-Control-Request-Method', 'GET')`?

Comment: Thanks @arut. Using request.setHeader('X-HTTP-Method-Override', 'GET'), worked!

Comment: Cool. Just posting this as answer in case others are searching for the same problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting ***X-HTTP-Method-Override*** header key should be the fix. Code snippet below:

```
request.setHeader('X-HTTP-Method-Override', 'GET')
```